# Hiding Horizontal Scroll bar in frozen columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a RadGrid in which I want the first two columns fixed. I got that by using this code:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgCallLogin" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True">
    <ClientSettings>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="true" FrozenColumnsCount="2">
        </Scrolling>
    </ClientSettings>
    <MasterTableView>
        --
        --
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Now I have a horizontal scroll bar in all the columns. Is there any way to show the scroll bar only in the non-frozen columns?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

No. There does not appear to be any way to achieve this (as you can imagine since this question has gone unanswered).  This is because it is the rgDataDiv that is scrolling, and it contains *all* of the columns.  The freeze column effect is actually setting display: none on the leftmost unfrozen column as you scroll.

FYI, there is sort of an alternate solution in that you can enable ClientSettings.Scrolling.EnableNextPrevFrozenColumns for button-based scrolling through the unfrozen columns.